# Unable to access SharePoint from a Trusted Domain

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker, trusted-domain

I have a 3-tier SharePoint 2013 on-premise deployed.  We have 4 domains with a 2-way trust across all.  The SharePoint Server is setup in ie: Domain1 and is working perfectly using Domain1 credentials.  Have added the other 3 domains to People Picker via PowerShell.

Now, Domain1, Domain2, and Domain3 were able to access the SharePoint using their respective credentials but Domain4 is not.  I am being prompted for credentials for 3 times but nothing happens after, as in nothing... no errors or prompts whatsoever.

I am able to populate the credentials in all domains through UPSA using the created service accounts in each domains.

Hope you can help me with my dilemma.  Many thanks.